# Gitlab CI/CD Pipeline Running Issue

Tags: angular, docker-compose, dockerfile, gitlab-ci-runner

Hi I am trying to learn the continious integration but I am facing the issue .

I have register my runner on the server , on the gitlab my runner is running from last around 40 minutes then it's stop . Sharing you the image below .
In the localhost my app is running perfect , no issues.

This is my Dockerfile:

```
# base image
FROM node:12.2.0 as build

# install chrome for protractor tests
RUN wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add -
RUN sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list'
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -yq google-chrome-stable

# set working directory
WORKDIR /app

# add `/app/node_modules/.bin` to $PATH
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

# install and cache app dependencies
COPY package.json /app/package.json
RUN npm install
RUN npm install -g @angular/cli@7.3.9

# add app
COPY . /app

# # run tests
# RUN ng test --watch=false
# RUN ng e2e --port 4202

# generate build
RUN ng build --output-path=dist

############
### prod ###
############

# base image
FROM nginx:1.16.1-alpine

# copy artifact build from the 'build environment'
COPY --from=build /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html

# expose port 80
EXPOSE 80

# run nginx
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

docker-compose file

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  example-prod:
    container_name: angular-app-prod
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - '5001:80'
```

when I am running my docker-compose , the image is building up and running the app without any problem.

Below is my gitlab-ci.yml file:

```
DEV-deploy:

  script:
    - docker-compose build --parallel
    - docker-compose up -d

  tags : ['angulardemo']

  only:
    - master
```

[image: GitLab Runner]

[image: Registered GitLab runner]

I don't know what's going wrong . please help me on this

Comment: check your firewall status, maybe the firewall stops the connection between gitlab runner and gitlab

Comment: And another bottleneck in your dockerfile is by installing npm packages every build time.

Comment: @AliTorki How to get rid of npm packages every build time

Comment: just let it install all packages for the first time and them comment npm install line. and when you installed a package, then uncomment that line. This is what I've done in my project.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks it's worked , I have the runner issue : 
I have run this following command on the server by installing fresh gitlab runner on the server:

```
Install gitlab runner--check this syntax 



 gitlab-runner register
    sudo usermod -aG docker gitlab-runner
    sudo nano /etc/sudoers
    gitlab-runner ALL= (ALL)NOPASSWD:ALL
    sudo gitlab-runner restart
    sudo gitlab-runner --debug start
```

If anyone can help me with the solution of the bottleneck( npm packages every build time) !! it's my great pleasure !!